# Redirect to a Link without Popup Menu in Browser

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I have two dropdown menus with submit button which redirect visitors to specific url base on choices from the dropdown menus.

The issue: When visitor click on the "submit" button, the browser show him a popup menu as show in the below screenshot. I need to disable this popup. Which means that visitor should land on the targeted url smoothly and directly.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QBNdb.png)

HTML

```
<form>
  <select id="carbrand">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab" selected="selected">Saab</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>

  <select id="carcolor">
    <option value="white">White</option>
    <option value="black" selected="selected">Black</option>
    <option value="red">Red</option>
    <option value="blue">Blue</option>
  </select>

  <br/><br/>

  <input id="btnCallURL" type="button" value="Call URL">  
</form>
```

Javascript

```
<script>

document.getElementById('btnCallURL').onclick = function() { 
    var carbrandObj = document.getElementById('carbrand');
    var carcolorObj = document.getElementById('carcolor');

    var carbrandValue = carbrandObj.options[carbrandObj.selectedIndex].value;
    var carColorValue = carcolorObj.options[carcolorObj.selectedIndex].value;

    jsCallUrl(carbrandValue, carColorValue);
}

function jsCallUrl(carbrandValue, carColorValue){

    var pageUrl = "";

    switch (carbrandValue){
        case "volvo":
            switch (carColorValue){
            case "white":
                pageUrl = "volvo-white-page-url.php";
                break;
            case "black":
                pageUrl = "volvo-black-page-url.php";
                break;
            default:
                pageUrl = "volvo-othercolor-page-url.php";
                break;
          }
          break;
        case "saab":
            switch (carColorValue){
            case "white":
                pageUrl = "saab-white-page-url.php";
                break;
            case "black":
                pageUrl = "saab-black-page-url.php";
                break;
            default:
                pageUrl = "saab-othercolor-page-url.php";
                break;
          }
          break;
    }

    alert(pageUrl);

    if (pageUrl != ""){
      location.href = "https://domain/" + pageUrl;
    }
}

</script>
```

Comment: remove the alert

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove this part of your code:

```
alert(pageUrl);
```

[Window alert() Method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_alert.asp)